# Solve the following EDO's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> They ask me to solve
> $$y' +2y + \int_{0}^{x} y(t)dt = f(x)$$ with $y(0)=0$ and
> $$
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0, & x < 5 \\
> 2, & x \geq 5 
> \end{cases}
> $$

I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Solve the following differential equation:
> $$y^\prime +2y + \int_{0}^{x} y(t)dt = f(x)\tag{1}$$
> where $y(0)=0$, and
> $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & x < 5 \\ 2 & x \geq 5 \end{cases}$$

Solution:

Assuming $t^\prime=\frac{dt}{dx}$ for any function $t$!

Substitute
\begin{align*}
u&=y+\int_{0}^{x} y(t)dt\\
u^\prime&=y^\prime+y(x)\frac{dx}{dx}-y(0)\frac{d(0)}{dx}\\
u^\prime&=y^\prime+y\\
\end{align*}
to get
\begin{align*}
u^\prime+u&=0& \forall\ x<5\tag{2}\\
u^\prime+u&=2& \forall\ x\ge5\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
Solving equation $(2)$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dx}&=-u\\
-\frac{du}{u}&=dx\\
-\int\frac{du}{u}&=\int dx\\
\ln u&=-x+c_1\\
u&=e^{-x+c_1}\\
u^\prime&=-e^{-x+c_1}\\
y^\prime+y&=-e^{-x+c_1}\\
y^\prime+y&=-e^{-x+\displaystyle\lim_{c_1\to-\infty}c_1}&(\because y^\prime(0)=y(0)=0\text{ from equation }1)\\
y^\prime+y&=0\\
y&=e^{-x+c_2}\\
y&=-e^{-x+\displaystyle\lim_{c_2\to-\infty}c_2}&(\because y(0)=0)\\
\Rightarrow y(x)&=0\ \forall\ x<5\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Solving equation $(3)$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dx}&=-u+2\\
-\frac{du}{u-2}&=dx\\
-\int\frac{du}{u-2}&=\int dx\\
\ln (u-2)&=-x+c_3\\
u&=e^{-x+c_3}+2\\
u^\prime&=-e^{-x+c_3}\\
y^\prime+y&=-e^{-x+c_3}\\
y^\prime(5)+y(5)&=-e^{-5+c_3}\\
\frac{d}{dx}(e^xy)&=-e^{c_3}\\
ye^x&=-e^{c_3}x+c_4\\
y&=-e^{c_3}xe^{-x}+c_4e^{-x}\\
y^\prime&=e^{c_3}e^{-x}(x-1)-c_4e^{-x}\\
\text{We know that }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad y^\prime(5)+2y(5)+\int_0^5 y(t)dt&=2\\
y^\prime(5)+2y(5)&=2&
\end{align*}
which is just one equation to obtain two variables $c_3$ and $c_4$.

**The question seems incomplete or I am mistaken.** Please comment!

Comment: You also know that $y(5)=0$ by continuity.

Comment: How do you know it's continuous at $x=5$?

Comment: Because it is a solution of a differential equation. Strictly speaking, it is not an ODE at $x=5$ due to the right side not being continuous, but any generalizing continuation concept demands at least continuity of the continuation.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. Assuming $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$, differentiate once to get
   $$
   y'' + 2y' + y = 0
   $$
   everywhere except $x = 5$ where the RHS does not exist. Can you solve that?
2. Once you know $y=y(x)$, the original equation gives you the value of the integration constant, which will be different on 2 intervals $(-\infty,5)$ and $(5,\infty)$.

Comment: No I can't,  sorry :(

Comment: @Maths4Life so what do you know about solving differential equations? This is a linear 2nd order differential equation, where did you encounter it? Is this a calculus class or a differential equations class? Which tools could you use?